# Probability distribution of the third side in triangle

Tags: probability, triangles

Given the two distributions of two sides of a triangle (for example, Uniform and Rayleigh) and the distribution of an angle between them (Uniform[0,Pi]), find the length of the third side.

What i came up with is:
Using the cosine law, I get the formula for the third side of a triangle:
$$
a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc\cos\alpha\
$$
However, the third term is dependent (is it?) on the first two.
Next i found in a book the method for multivariate PDF transformation using jacobian and inverse function (even though in my case it splits in two domains). But there I came to a stop, as in the end I have to integrate over the second and third parameter in order to get a one dimensional distribution, and there i still fail to get the right boundaries.

I'll really appreciate any help or tips on this problem.

Edit: Forgot to mention that the three mentioned random variables are independent.

Edit2: Sorry for the long delay.
Here's what I came up with:
In short, I have to sum the next value for all branch cuts:
$$W_{\eta_1}\left(y_1\right) = \int\limits_{y_2, y_3} w_{\xi^3}\left (\phi \left (y^3 \right ),y_2,y_3 \right ) \cdot \left |\frac{\partial \phi(y^3)}{\partial y_1} \right | dy_2 \; dy_3$$
However, the resulting integral is (as it might be seen) not that simple.

Is it the only way solve this problem, or are there another ways&

Comment: Do you mean find distribution of length of third side? Not just the length itself?

Answer (score 0):

To find distribution of third side, $Z$, given distributions of two other sides, $X$ and $Y$, and angle $A$ it boils down to finding distribution of $L=Z^{2}=X^{2}+Y^{2}-2XY\cos(A)$. Since distribution of $Z$ is given by CDF
$$F_{Z}(z)=P(Z\leq t)=P(Z^{2}\leq t^{2})=P(L\leq t^{2})$$
So finding CDF of L will help us find CDF of $Z$. But this can be quite messy because you have two calculate distribution of $X^{2}$, $Y^{2}$, and $2XY\cos(A)$ then distribution of $X^{2}+Y^{2}-2XY\cos(A)$. I have feeling tis won't come to a closed form. But if you wanted to get maybe a guess what it could be you could always simulate $X$, $Y$, and $A$ and use those observations to find simulations of $Z^{2}$ which give you some idea of what it may look like

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
Certainly, I can use the simulation results, but that's not exactly what I need.
If I wont be able to come up with a closed form solution, I'll have to resort to some approximation.

However I'm still looking for some sources (books maybe?), where some problems of this kind are solved. I strongly believe that there are some, but I just cant find them yet.